# Updating Like Button without Refreshing The Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my Like button,

```
<a class="wst-click update_data" wst-href="{% url 'data:like' content.id %}" href="{% url 'data:like' content.id %}" >{{ data.likes.count }} Like</a>
```

This is what I'm doing for 'Like' functionality,

```
$('.wst-click').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var this_ = $(this);
    var wstURL = this_.attr('wst-href');

    $.ajax({
        url: wstURL,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $('.update_data').text(data);
        }
    })
});
```

So, when I press the Like button instead of Returning the number of new Likes, it's returning the raw html code of entire webpage. How can I fix that?

Comment: specify dataType in ajax. Also check your webservice url

Comment: @VIJAYABALDHANAPAL Sir, I don't know AJAX, How can I do that?

Comment: please check the wstURL what value it has, is it the right url to your webservice ?

Comment: @VIJAYABALDHANAPAL Yes Sir, It's the right URL. It points toward the view that handles Like button functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working perfectly alright. I have added dummy example here.

```
<a class="wst-click update_data" wst-href="data/like/10" href="data/like/10" >11 Like</a>

$('.wst-click').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var this_ = $(this);
    var wstURL = this_.attr('wst-href');
    $('.update_data').text('12 Like');

    /*$.ajax({
        url: wstURL,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            var like_text = $(data).find('.update_data').html();
            $('.update_data').html(like_text);
        }
    });*/
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tszbxe98/)

Comment: Sir, it's returning the Entire webpage no the number of new likes as I click like button

Comment: Than it may be problem with you response. I just created testing demo. Because I don't have your response.

Comment: Sir, How can I separate out the new Likes from the entire webpage which `$('.update_data').text(data);` is returning currently?

Comment: Can you display what you are get in data variable?

Comment: Sir, i'm getting the raw html code of entire webpage in data variable. As I press like button it replaces the Like button with raw html code of current webpage.

Comment: I got it. I have changed my code. Check success block.

Comment: WOW, Working perfectly fine :) Than You very much Sir :)